# Android MediaCodec : Decoding is success but encoded file is not playable

Tags: android, video, compression, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying to write a video compression application that will run on Jellybean version of Android. Till now I could decode the given input to video/raw format and it is playable with mplayer. My problem is that when I Encode this video/raw item into video/avc format with width = 320, height = 240, bitRate = (480*1024), frameRate = 20, iFrameInterval = 7 and colorFormat = YUV420Planar, the output file is not playable by just double clicking on it. Can anyone suggest me a way to play it using any player.? Or can you tell me if I had made any mistake in giving the above parameters like bitrate, framerate etc..

Thanks in advance.! :)